# Unable to escape command

Tags: bash

I am writing a mysqldump bash backup script, but can't get it to escape the password correctly.

At the top if have:

```
PLESKPASS=( `cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` )
```

Using 'set -x' I can see this returns:

```
+ echo '$AES-128-CBC$ssdvgdfvgRipfbUZcg==$Mi3asdNOTREALddnerpTTzVhYBgKriyBA='
$AES-128-CBC$ssdvgdfvgRipfbUZcg==$Mi3asdNOTREALddnerpTTzVhYBgKriyBA=
```

Which is fine.

My command has the following:

```
COMMAND='mysqldump -R -a --single-transaction -uadmin -p'$PLESKPASS' '$DB' > mysqldumps/'$DB'.sql'
```

The $DB string is returned correctly, however the Plesk password isn't, it runs as:

```
COMMAND='mysqldump -R -a --single-transaction -uadmin -p$AES-128-CBC$ssdvgdfvgRipfbUZcg==$Mi3asdNOTREALddnerpTTzVhYBgKriyBA= phpmyadmin_5IAf0u4U5vXa > mysqldumps/phpmyadmin_5IAf0u4U5vXa.sql'
```

Which looks ok, but doesn't work without the password being enclosed in quotes.

Ive tried many different combinations to get this to work. Using '\'' before and after, doubles quotes here and there, "'", "\'" etc to no avail and it's slowly driving me insane as I'm sure its something simple, but what you don't know will always seem complicated!

**UPDATE:**
I played around with the code some more, and through trial and error and trying each of these:

```
PLESKPASS="$(</etc/psa/.psa.shadow)"
PLESKPASS=$(eval echo -e `</etc/psa/.psa.shadow`)
PLESKPASS=( `cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow`
```

Which all returned the password correctly, I noticed someone used $() and on a whim tried that before my command, so it went from:

> COMMAND='mysqldump -R -a --single-transaction -uadmin -p'$PLESKPASS'
>   '$DB' > mysqldumps/'$DB'.sql'

to

> COMMAND=$(mysqldump -R -a --single-transaction -uadmin -p$PLESKPASS
>   $DB > mysqldumps/$DB.sql)

And it gives the desired result! I am still none the wiser, many thanks for everyones help.

Comment: Don't give away your keys like that.

Comment: @devnull The key contains a string that is either a subtle clue or an insanely cool coincidence.

Comment: @Carsten damn, you spotted it! Also the original key had lots of characters hacked out and random characters inserted before posting it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
pleskpass="$(cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow)"
command="mysqldump -R -a --single-transaction -uadmin -p'$PLESKPASS' '$DB' > mysqldumps/'$DB'.sql"
```

Using `"` should keep the `'` in the string.

Comment: You don't need the quotes for the assignment because word splitting is not performed on expansions in assignments, `pleskpass=$(cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow)` is fine.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth i remember having many problems when trying to do it without the quotes in other cases. Like assigning one variable to the other trying to keep newlines. So i always do it like that to be on the safe side.

Comment: `foo=$'foo\nbar'; quux=${foo}; echo "[${quux}]"` works as it should, but I'd be glad to see an example where it fails. There are not many expressions where quoting is not needed, but this is one of them (the `case` statement is another prominent one). I used to do this too but since it's not needed and I have a feeling that `bash` unnecessarily parses the string an additional time if you quote I stopped doing this.

Comment: Tried this, but it generates: `COMMAND='mysqldump -R -a --single-transaction -admin -p'\''J5jhsdv89E20='\'' '\'''\'' > mysqldumps/'\'''\''.sql'` however the actual code is `COMMAND="mysqldump -R -a --single-transaction -admin -p'$PLESKPASS' '$DB' > mysqldumps/'$DB'.sql"`

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes around the whole variable, single quotes around the passwords work:

```
PLESKPASS=123
DB=testdb
COMMAND="mysqldump -R -a --single-transaction -uadmin -p'$PLESKPASS' '$DB' > mysqldumps/$DB.sql"
echo $COMMAND
```

prints out

```
mysqldump -R -a --single-transaction -uadmin -p'123' 'testdb' > mysqldumps/testdb.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first command is creating an array.

Try this:

```
PLESKPASS=$(</etc/psa/.psa.shadow)
mysqldump -R -a --single-transaction -uadmin -p"'$PLESKPASS'" "$DB" > mysqldumps/"$DB".sql
```

Comment: You should put `$pleskpass` and `$db` in `"` to make sure spaces and other oddities are kept.

Comment: Thanks I did though usually spaces are not expected in those variables.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried it but doesnt work for me. The values are returned in the correct way, but the password isn't enclosed in single quotes so it doesnt accept it.

Comment: `mysqldump` doesn't need password in single quote. Why is that a requirement?

Comment: It will do if the password contains characters interpreted via bash. The password used by Plesk for MySQL is AES encrypted and contains a $  and == signs... thats my understanding of it.